# Looking for a way to save game data in my text based game in android studio (java)

Tags: java, android, 2d-games

I've scoured for the answer for this. I have a simple text based game. I make a choice with a radio button, and confirm it with a button click. I've set the game to save for when I change to landscape from portrait view.

But I cannot for the life of me find how to save the game when the back button is pressed.

I'd like to have a simple menu on the title screen with three buttons, one of them being "Continue" which would restore the game's saved settings. And obviously, one in the action menu I already have set up which would reset all the game data.

I've tried sharedPreferences etc. if someone can tell me the way to save the game data by using SQL so no user can mess with the data, that'd be better.

Thank you in advance for you help.

on edit I realized my question is not specific enough. I am trying to retain the state of a TextView which I am modifying with user choices, thus changing the text. Every time the app is restarted, the first text loads.

Comment: It really depends on how much data you want to to save - Is it just a few simple variables, or is it a massive game with many variables, collections, and all sorts of complicated data structures?

Comment: Really there isn't much data at the moment to save. Just how far along the user is in the story. But I plan on adding others things so perhaps the SQL is better. Still though, as far as getting started on this I'm completely lost.

Comment: The easiest way (though very improper) would just be to store it in a text file. There are plenty of resources available on writing and reading from a text file and it had a far far lower barrier to entry than SQL

Comment: @StevenLowes I don't really agree. SQLlite is pretty well implementable, and you do not have to do anything with reading and writing files.

Comment: If I only needed to store, say 5 simple variables, I would just use a text file. It feels silly to set up an SQL database for such a simple task. If it is expected that the data stored will grow more complicated, It could be worth getting into SQL. Bear in mind that it is probably a lot easier for you to set up an SQL database than it is for someone that has never used SQL before, as we can assume is the case with OP

Comment: Thank you though I'm not really looking for the easiest solution. I'm looking for the best working solution so as my coding prowess becomes better I'll already know how to save games the right way. No, I've never used SQL.

Comment: question is off-topic: asking why this does not work without providing the related code.

Comment: It sounds like you're implementing something like a CYOA (choose your own adventure)... instead of saving "the text" at the moment of save, an alternative could be to store the choices the user made to get to where they are. You can then replay them when you restore a game (either interactively -- like fast-forwarding through a show), or off-screen and just show the end result. If there were any random events, you would also need to record the specific outcomes with this approach.

Comment: Best video, got it working. A text file was the easiest way, thank you all.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhBBWVydcH8

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on how much information you want to save, but if it's very little I'd look in to shared preferences which saves key value pares. If it contains a bit more, you should look in to SQLLite which is just a database for your app on the device.

### Further reading:

#### SharedPreferences:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

#### SQLLite:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried serialization? Put the informations in a file, like a text file, then simply un-serialize it and take back the informations. You can always encrypt it if you don't want anyone to change the datas, like a real game save file.